# Elixir/Phoenix redirect to the current page

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I'm trying to implement different languages in the app. So what I've done is created lang variable in Session in the db, which keeps the current selected language.

The problem is that i'm calling and updating the value through update action:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "session" => session_params}) do
session = Repo.get!(Session, id)
changeset = Session.changeset(session, session_params)

case Repo.update(changeset) do
  {:ok, _session} ->
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Session updated successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :tableshow))
  {:error, changeset} ->
    render(conn, "edit.html", session: session, changeset: changeset)
end
end
```

, which redirects it to the specific path(here: page_path). My question: is it possible to get the current path and redirect to it, once the action is called? So then, when you change language it's not just redirects you to one specific page all the time, instead it just reloads the current page, where the action was called?
Language selectors are in header in every page.So i want the page just to reload.Any suggestions?

Additional info: I'm calling the action from the app.html.eex like this

```
<%= render Pos1.SessionView, "session_en.html", changeset: @changesetlang, action: session_path(@conn, :update, @session) %>
```

where session_en.html is:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
<%= hidden_input f, :lang, value: "1" %>
<%= submit "EN", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using to add the link/form to this action from all the pages in your app?

Comment: Hey @Dogbert here is the form/link code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to add another `hidden_input` with the current page's URL, and redirect to that from the `update` action.

In `app.html.eex`, change the `render` call to pass `@conn` as `conn`:

```
<%= render Pos1.SessionView, "session_en.html", changeset: @changesetlang, action: session_path(@conn, :update, @session), conn: @conn %>
```

then add the new `hidden_input` to `session_en.html.eex`

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= hidden_input f, :lang, value: "1" %>
  <%= hidden_input f, :redirect_to, value: @conn.request_path %>
  <%= submit "EN", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and finally, in the controller, change the `redirect` call to:

```
|> redirect(to: session_params["redirect_to"])
```

Edit: You probably want to restrict the `redirect_to` to point only to your site. You can do that with a simple `case`:

```
redirect_to = case session_params["redirect_to"] do
  path = "/" <> _ -> path
  _ -> "/some/default/path"
end
```

and then

```
|> redirect(to: redirect_to)
```

Thank you Scott S. for pointing this out.

Comment: Wow thank you! I've just updated the code, and it works. I forgot about request_path.

Comment: OFFTOPIC: Hey, can I ask you one more question? The @session in controller is Repo.get!(Session, id), but as I've putted it in app.html.eex, then I need to create variable  Repo.get!(Session, id) in each separate controllers (instead in just app.html.eex). So, Is it possible to put it where [:changeset, :conn, :view_module, :view_template] are, so then I won't need to make this variable it every single controller (for all pages).

Comment: In other words, is there a "controller" for the app.html.eex where I can add code (for variable and changeset) so that it will be on every page?

Comment: Be careful redirecting to a user supplied location. This kind of functionality is sometimes abused by fraudsters and phishers to make a link look legitimate. I suggest implementing something to ensure the submitted redirect_to value is on your domain, or a path with no domain at all.

Comment: @ScottS. you're right, thank you, I've edited the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @Ilya You should look into creating a [Plug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug). You'll probably want to use this function to store the session in the conn: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3. I also recommend reading through that documentation page to learn more about what you can do with a conn in a Plug.

Comment: Hey @ScottS. Thanks for mentioning that, definitely something to consider!

Comment: @Dogbert Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: @ScottS. Doesn't redirect/1 handle that? When I tried changing the `redirect_to` field to "google.com" using the inspector, I got `the :to option in redirect expects a path but was "google.com"`. From this message, I assume redirect/1 ensures that no external links are passed in.

Comment: @Fomentia It does now, unless using the external keyword, but I don’t believe it did when the question was posted.